# accessing my container via my ip:host not working anymore

Tags: docker, nginx

I use docker/docker-compose and nginx on my own server.
I was able to access to my container via external port
like `my_adress:8080`
then i made a redirect via nginx

```
{
listen 80
servername my_adress.8080
return 301 https://my_adress.8080
}
```

and then i removed the nginx conf.
I restarted nginx services
but now i can't access to `http://my_adress:8080` anymore
there is an automatic redirect **301** to `https://my_adress` without port 8080

I search online how to remove nginx cache or something similar by didn't find it
i searched in https://serverfault.com/questions/825331/nginx-still-redirects-even-though-i-removed-the-rule-from-the-conf
but diden't find solution

when i do `service docker status`
i get in *CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service*

```
/usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.19.0.3 -container-port 80
```

Any ideas why i doesn't work anymore?

Comment: what's the return when ```service nginx status``` and  when ```docker ps```? In the nginx file third line, shouldn't it be  ```servername localhost:8080``` since I suppose you've already published the container's port?

Comment: Thanks for answering, i found out the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem was.

I was using the image https://hub.docker.com/r/onlyoffice/documentserver
and i set up the https config

see "Running ONLYOFFICE Docs using HTTPS" in this page :
https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/docs-community-install-docker.aspx

And on this image they were an automatic proxy to redirect https to https, so i was not linked to the nginx conf on my server it was only inside the docker-proxy

So the 2 solutions that i found:

- remove the https configuration so it would be available in http
- or binding host server port 443 (https) to the 443 port of the ONLYOFFICE
  container, so the redirection works